# Calculating Conditional Probability.

Tags: probability

Events $B$ and $C$ are dependent on event $A$.
$B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive. 
$Prob (A \cap B) = 0.3$ and $Prob( A \cap C) = 0.2$ .
What is $Prob(C | A)$.

I know:
 $$Prob(C|A) = Prob( A \cap C) \div Prob(A)$$

How to calculate $Prob(A)$?

Comment: Hint: Argue and use that we can write $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$Pr(E\cup F)=Pr(E)+Pr(F)-Pr(E\cap F)$$

$B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive implies $Pr(B\cap C)=0$

$B$ and $C$ are collectively exhaustive implies $B\cup C=\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is the entire sample space.

$A\cap \Omega = A$ since $A$ is by definition a subset of the sample space.

---

$Pr(A)=Pr(A\cap \Omega)=\dots$